# Sending Data from Swift to PHP but returns nothing

Tags: php, swift

I am trying to send data from SWIFT to PHP.

Swift seems to be sending correct data using POST.

```
let url:NSURL = NSURL(string: url)!
let session = URLSession.shared
let request = NSMutableURLRequest(url: url as URL)
    request.httpMethod = "POST"

let paramString = "table_id='1'"
    request.httpBody = paramString.data(using: String.Encoding.utf8)
```

However, when the PHP receives it, it returns nothing.

```
$contents = $_REQUEST['table_id']; 
$abc = $contents;

$sql = "SELECT * FROM menu_main_items WHERE table_id='".$abc."'";

if ($result = mysqli_query($con, $sql)) {
    $resultArray = array();
    $tempArray = array();
    while($row = $result->fetch_object()){
        $tempArray = $row;
        array_push($resultArray, $tempArray);
}
echo json_encode($resultArray);
```

What do you think the problem seems to be?

Comment: `NSURLConnection.sendAsynchronousRequest`...

Answer (score 0):

Pretty sure you need to do this since it is unicode_utf_8

```
$contents = htmlentities($_REQUEST['table_id']);
```